# I want to get ranking number in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get ranking number in Laravel.

DB is here.

```
id Bigint
name string
point BigInt
.....
```

I want to get ranking number in point column.
What should I do?

now code is this.

```
User::where('id', 1)->first();
```

if I have these datas.

```
id name score ...
1    AA      10
2    CD      10
3    ER      40
4    DR      5
```

I want to get ranking number
ex) id 1 => 2 (or3)
ex) id 3 => 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rank as below:

```
User::selectRaw("SELECT id, name, point,  FIND_IN_SET( point, (
                 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT point ORDER BY point DESC ) FROM 
                user )  
               ) AS rank
                FROM user")

        ->get()
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to get ranking number.
My explanation was inadequate.

Comment: what ranking do you want?

Comment: Edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here is the raw query :

```
SELECT id,name,point,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM user u, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY point;
```

You can write it in laravel as follows :

```
DB::select("SELECT id,name,point,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM user u, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY point;");
```